# Overloading bitwise OR('|') for chaining operations not working as expected

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

I am trying overload bitwise OR '|' operator so that I can chain different operations one after another.

I have implemented the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    explicit Test(vector<int> vdata) : data_(vdata) { }

    vector<int>& operator()()
    {
        return data_;
    }

    template<typename Pred>
    Test operator | (Pred P)
    {
        *this = P;
        return *this;
    }

    vector<int> data_;
};

template <typename Con, typename Pred>
Con Transform(Con& C, Pred P)
{
    vector<int> res;

    transform(begin(C()), end(C()),back_inserter(res),  P);

    return Con(res);
}

template <typename Con, typename Pred>
Con Filter(Con& C, Pred P)
{
    vector<int> res;

    remove_copy_if(begin(C()), end(C()), back_inserter(res), P);

    return Con(res);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vdata{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

    auto DoubleIt = [](int& v) {
        return v *= 2;
    };

    auto Remove_Lteq4 = [](auto v) {
        return v <= 4;
    };

    auto Remove_divideby3=[](auto v) 
    {
        return !(v % 3);
    };

    Test test(vdata);

    Test test1 =  
     test | Filter(test, Remove_Lteq4) |  
     Transform(test, DoubleIt) | 
     Filter(test, Remove_divideby3);

    // output
    for (auto v : test1())
        cout << v << " ";            
}
```

The code is working fine giving expected output on Cxxdroid 2.0_arm offline compiler, C++14/C++17, but I am getting different results on online compilers

Input:
vector = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
Operations applied in sequence are
Filter values <= 4 then multiply the remaining by 2 then filter values divisible by 3

Results offline compiler (Cxxdroid)
expected output: 10, 14, 16, 20, 22
actual output: 10, 14, 16, 20, 22

Online compiler
actual output: 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11 (this is actually the output you would get if you only apply remove_divideby3 function to the input).

I am struggling with it for some time now and unable to figure out the reason for different output. Can someone please tell where I am making the mistake.
The code works fine if I apply just one opetation at a time.

I will also be very greatful if someone could answer addition queries.

1. Do I need to write copy constructor/copy assignment, move constructor and move assignment.
2. Is my usage of objects correct in terms of passing and returning the objects by value and by reference. I think the issue is somewhere here, probabily passing an object where a reference is needed.
3. Is there a need to overload '|' at global level.

Note: using namespace std; is used for convenience purpose only as I had typed the code on mobile.

Thank you

Comment: @L.F. 
I have edited my post and added the reason for "using namespace std;". I know it's pitfalls.

Comment: Seriously, I don't think `using namespace std;` has a second justified reason other than resolving ADL in extremely rare edge cases.  But I'll take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class F>
struct pipe_func {
  F f;

  template<class Lhs>
  friend auto operator|( Lhs&& lhs, pipe_func rhs ) {
    return rhs.f( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs) );
  }
};
template<class F>
pipe_func(F)->pipe_func<F>;
```

there is a building block for you.  A `pipe_target` takes a function, and when piped things feeds it to the function and returns the result.

Now suppose you want to write filter.

```
template<class Pred>
auto Filter( Pred p ) {
  return pipe_func{[p]( auto&& container ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    using R = std::decay_t< decltype(container) >;
    R retval;
    std::remove_copy_if( begin(container), end(container), std::back_inserter(retval), p );
    return retval;
  }};
}
```

so `filter` is a function taking a predicate.

It returns a `pipe_func`.  The `pipe_func` has a lambda in it that applies the predicate.

Transform is similar:

```
template<class Pred>
auto Transform( Pred p ) {
  return pipe_func{[p]( auto&& container ) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    using R = std::decay_t< decltype(container) >;
    R retval;
    std::transform( begin(container), end(container), std::back_inserter(retval), p );
    return retval;
  }};
}
```

Test code looks like:

```
std::vector<int> test1 =  
 vdata | Filter(Remove_Lteq4) |  
 Transform(DoubleIt) | 
 Filter(Remove_divideby3);
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/add18f72d2796f6c).

Now, a solution where we can pipe into functions taking two arguments is a bit fishy; the function still thinks it takes 2 arguments, so passing it its second is tricky.

I'd avoid it.   Any solution would be a hack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's quite an elegant solution but if you don't mind I will wait for some more time before accepting it as an answer. And indeed I was struggling trying to pass second argument to pipe function.

Comment: Can you please explain this line 

template<class F> pipe_func(F)->pipe_func<F>; 

I didn't understand this fully, what it is doing? My understanding is it pipe_func takes template parameter F and returns an object of type pipe_func<F> and return type is specified as trailing return type. But if so then why this

template<class T> struct S{ }; and
template<class T>
     Sf(T) -> S<T>; fails to compile? But compiles only if I put auto before Sf(T). Or is that function template instantiation or some shortcut form I do not understand.

Comment: @neitron template construction guide

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this (I rearranged the pipes to make it easier to read):

```
Test test1 =  
 test | Filter(test, Remove_Lteq4)
      | Transform(test, DoubleIt)
      | Filter(test, Remove_divideby3);
```

Let's start from the back. What does `Filter(test, Remove_divideby3)` do? It gives back a container that is all the elements from `test` that satisfy `Remove_divideby3`. But `test` is what you started with, it doesn't depend on anything in any part of this operation. It doesn't matter what the other `Filter` or `Transform` return, since none of those values is used as input into this `Filter`.

That's why what you're getting is no different from having written:

```
Test test1 = Filter(test, Remove_divideby3);
```

Your adapters have *either* take the range as an argument:

```
Filter(Transform(Filter(test, Remove_Lteq4), DoubleIt), Remove_divideby3)
```

*or* use pipes:

```
test | Filter(Remove_Lteq4) | Transform(DoubleIt) | Filter(Remove_divideby3)
```

Not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Barry for the answer. I was thinking that starting from left to right, lhs will be test object and rhs would be first filter. This will produce temporary modified test object which will then serves as lhs for the next Filter or Transform operation and so on, then the last temporary test object will get assigned to test1, the final result. I didn't realized that everytime I am passing the original unmodified test object.
I am bit confued now regarding how will I access underlying vector obect in Filter if I choose to use pipes?
Can you also please answer other queries?

Comment: @NeutronStar Well, think about it. What does `Filter(f)` need to do such that `x | Filter(f)` filters `x` using `f`?

Comment: I was thinking on the lines of specialization, functor, global overloading for pipe but it appears I need to struggle for a longer time.